# Crypt incursion on servos

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Will [Crypt Incursion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrypt%20Incursion%5d) work on artifact creatures such as snakes that have been destroyed?

I tried it on my friend who made 22 snake artifact creatures and almost all of them died so they went to his graveyard, and I used it, but he said it did not count.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as though you are talking about artifact creature tokens, not just artifact creatures. If this is the case, then your friend is correct. You know it is a token because some effect created them, rather than them existing as actual cards in the game.

> 110.5. Some effects put tokens onto the battlefield. A token is a marker used to represent any permanent that isn’t represented by a card.

Note that it is common to use things that look like cards as the markers to represent these tokens, but those things are not "cards" in the sense that a [Mountain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMountain%5d) is a card; they don't go in your deck, etc.

Tokens work differently than cards when they die. While they do enter the graveyard, they immediately cease to exist before you have a chance to do anything such as casting [Crypt Incursion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrypt%20Incursion%5d). Therefore you cannot exile them from the graveyard.

> 110.5f A token that’s in a zone other than the battlefield ceases to exist. This is a state-based action; see rule 704.

Also note that even if the tokens did stay in the graveyard, it wouldn't matter, because Crypt Incursion specifically says "creature **cards**"; and as mentioned earlier, tokens are not cards.

Comment: Also, tokens aren't cards, and Crypt Incursion specifically affects cards.

Answer (score 3):

The text of [Crypt Incursion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrypt%20Incursion%5d) is:

> Exile all creature **cards** from target player's graveyard. You gain 3
>   life for each card exiled this way.

What you're trying to do doesn't work for two reasons:

First, tokens aren't cards, and Crypt Incursion specifically asks for cards, so this doesn't work.

Second, creature tokens cease to exist when they die. They trigger effects that trigger when a creature goes to the graveyard, but they don't stay in the graveyard like cards, they just cease to exist, so you can't exile them as they are not in the graveyard.